# sorting by common item

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm in a situation where I need to sort lists based on how common an item is among them. For example I have these lists:

```
s1 = [a, b, f, d, c]
s2 = [b, f, e, a]
s3 = [c, f, b]
```

So, after the operation these will become:

```
s1 = [b, f, a, c, d]
s2 = [b, f, a, e]
s3 = [b, f, c]
```

b and f are common in all lists, then next is either a or c which is both common in two lists.

Is there any easier way in achieving this in python instead of writing my own implementation?

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one item in the same list?

Comment: No, each list will have unique items.

Comment: Though its OK if your solution requires to duplicate some items

Comment: What about `c`? It's as "common" as `a`.

Comment: Yes, either a or c will come next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'c']
b = ['b', 'f', 'e', 'a']
c = ['c', 'f', 'b']

ctr = Counter(a + b + c)
common = ctr.most_common()

>>> common
[('b', 3), ('f', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('e', 1), ('d', 1)]

common_list_vals = [t[0] for t in common]

>>> common_list_vals
['b', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']

>>> for my_list in [a, b, c]:
        print [val for val in common_list_vals if val in my_list]
['b', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'd']
['b', 'f', 'a', 'e']
['b', 'f', 'c']
```

Note that there are multiple 'valid' answers, e.g.:

```
['f', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
['f', 'b', 'a', 'e']
['f', 'b', 'c']
```

and

```
['f', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
['f', 'b', 'a', 'e']
['f', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Counter` for count all list elements for all three list , then sort them based on  their count:

```
from collections import Counter
listCounts= Counter(s1+s2+s3)
listOflists = [s1,s2,s3]
for listi in listOflists:
    sorted(listi, key=listCounts.get, reverse = True)
```

Output:

```
s1 = [b, f, a, c, d]
s2 = [b, f, a, e]
s3 = [f, b, c]   # Because `b` and `f` has same count maybe they replaced in output
```

Comment: `key=lambda x:listsCounts[x]` could also be replaced by `key=listCounts.get`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
>>> lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'c']
>>> lst2 = ['b', 'f', 'e', 'a']
>>> lst3 = ['c', 'f', 'b']
>>> lst = lst1 + lst2 + lst3
>>> lst1 = sorted(lst1, key=lambda x: lst.count(x), reverse=True)
>>> lst2 = sorted(lst2, key=lambda x: lst.count(x), reverse=True)
>>> lst3 = sorted(lst3, key=lambda x: lst.count(x), reverse=True)
```

**Output:**

```
['b', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'd']
['b', 'f', 'a', 'e']
['f', 'b', 'c']
```